# ListView issues

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

I have an little issues with an ListView component, when I click on a row the Application capture the touch event but but the row isn't focused!

Any ideas?

This is the XML of listview  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                             android:id="@+id/categoriestab_main"
                             android:orientation="vertical"
                             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                             android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
                             >



                    <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/categorieslist"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
                            android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFFFF"

                    />

             </LinearLayout>
```

And this is a layout of a single row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"



    >

      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/category_image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/no_foto" 

       />

         <TextView
            style="@style/categories_title"
            android:id="@+id/category_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:singleLine="true"   
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/category_image"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want a click effect on the row, or do you want to change that rows bgcolor to make it appear selected?

Comment: The first one, I would like the click effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your RelativeLayout, remove the `background` you have added and instead just have the background color on the ListView. That background color is blocking the click effect.

Comment: I wish offer you a big beer! Thanks !